# Python Google OR Tools CP. Updating constraints to prevent multiple jobs running simultaneously

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

Python/Google OR Tools newbie.  Update to the following code.  It is currently resulting in each job having its best makespan, but they are running simultaneously across machines.  I attempted to add a AddNoOverlap/AddCumulative constraint for machines/jobs, when when I run it against the jobs it results in infeasible if any thing less than the number of jobs is provided as the capacity.

This is our code:

```
# Initialize a defaultdict to store the processing times for each job and task
jobs_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

# Iterate over the dictionary and populate the defaultdict
for key, value in validPlatTarPhaseDict.items():
    machine, job, task = key[0], key[1], key[2]
    jobs_dict[job][task].append((value, machine))

# Convert the defaultdict into a list of lists
jobs = []
for job, tasks in jobs_dict.items():
    job_list = []
    for task, processing_times in tasks.items():
        task_list = [(processing_time, machine) for processing_time, machine in processing_times]
        job_list.append(task_list)
    jobs.append(job_list)

############################################################################################################################################
############################################################################################################################################
################

class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        """Called at each new solution."""
        print('Solution %i, time = %f s, objective = %i' %
              (self.__solution_count, self.WallTime(), self.ObjectiveValue()))
        self.__solution_count += 1

def jobshop():
    # DATA
    
    num_jobs = len(jobs)
    all_jobs = range(num_jobs)

    num_machines = platDetail['Plat ID (p)'].count()
    all_machines = range(num_machines)

    # Model the flexible jobshop problem.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    horizon = 0
    for job in jobs:
        for task in job:
            max_task_duration = 0
            for alternative in task:
                max_task_duration = max(max_task_duration, alternative[0])
            horizon += max_task_duration

    print('Horizon = %i' % horizon)

    # Global storage of variables.
    intervals_per_resources = collections.defaultdict(list)
    starts = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
    durations = {} # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
    ends = {} # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
    presences = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id, alt_id).
    all_intervals = {} # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
    job_starts = []
    job_ends = []
    job_intervals = []
    
    # Scan the jobs and create the relevant variables and intervals.
    for job_id in all_jobs:
        job = jobs[job_id]
        num_tasks = len(job)
        previous_end = None
        for task_id in range(num_tasks):
            task = job[task_id]

            min_duration = task[0][0]
            max_duration = task[0][0]

            num_alternatives = len(task)
            all_alternatives = range(num_alternatives)

            for alt_id in range(1, num_alternatives):
                alt_duration = task[alt_id][0]
                min_duration = min(min_duration, alt_duration)
                max_duration = max(max_duration, alt_duration)
           
            # Create main interval for the task.
            suffix_name = '_j%i_t%i' % (job_id, task_id)
            start = model.NewIntVar(arr_times[job_id], horizon, 'start' + suffix_name)
            duration = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                                       'duration' + suffix_name)
            end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix_name)
            interval = model.NewIntervalVar(start, duration, end,
                                            'interval' + suffix_name)

            # Store the start/duration/ends for the solution.
            starts[(job_id, task_id)] = start
            durations[(job_id, task_id)] = duration
            ends[(job_id, task_id)] = end
            all_intervals[(job_id, task_id)] = interval

            # Add precedence with previous task in the same job.
            if previous_end is not None:
                model.Add(start >= previous_end)
            previous_end = end
            
            # Create alternative intervals.
            if num_alternatives > 1:
                l_presences = []
                l_intervals = []
                for alt_id in all_alternatives:
                    alt_suffix = '_j%i_t%i_a%i' % (job_id, task_id, alt_id)
                    l_presence = model.NewBoolVar('presence' + alt_suffix)
                    l_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + alt_suffix)
                    l_duration = task[alt_id][0]
                    l_end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + alt_suffix)
                    l_interval = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
                        l_start, l_duration, l_end, l_presence,
                        'interval' + alt_suffix)
                    l_presences.append(l_presence)

                    # Link the primary/global variables with the local ones.
                    model.Add(start == l_start).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
                    model.Add(duration == l_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
                    model.Add(end == l_end).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)

                    # Add the local interval to the right machine.
                    intervals_per_resources[task[alt_id][1]].append(l_interval)
                    
                    # Store the presences for the solution.
                    presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)] = l_presence                
                    l_intervals.append(l_interval)
                    
                #Add Cumulative
                model.AddNoOverlap(l_intervals)
                model.AddCumulative(l_intervals, [1 for _ in l_intervals], 1) 

                # Select exactly one presence variable.
                model.AddExactlyOne(l_presences)
                                             
            else:
                intervals_per_resources[task[0][1]].append(interval)
                presences[(job_id, task_id, 0)] = model.NewConstant(1)
                      
        #store the end time for each job    
        job_ends.append(previous_end)
   
    # Create machines constraints.
    for machine_id in all_machines:
        intervals = intervals_per_resources[machine_id]
        if len(intervals) >= 1:
            model.AddNoOverlap(intervals) 
      
    for job_id in all_jobs:
        job = jobs[job_id]
        suffix_name = '_j%i' % (job_id)
        job_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'job_start' + suffix_name)
        job_duration = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon,
                                    'job_duration' + suffix_name)
        jobs_ends = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'job_end' + suffix_name)
        job_interval = model.NewIntervalVar(job_start, job_duration, jobs_ends, 'job interval' + suffix_name)

        # Link the job variables with the task ones.
        model.Add(job_start == start)
        model.Add(job_duration == duration)
        
        #update lists
        job_starts.append(job_start)
        job_intervals.append(job_interval)
    #     print(job_start)
    #     print(job_duration)
    #     print(jobs_ends)
    # print(job_intervals)
    model.AddCumulative(job_intervals, [1 for _ in job_intervals], 30) 
#    model.AddNoOverlap(job_intervals)

    # Makespan objective
    makespan = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
    model.AddMaxEquality(makespan, job_ends)
    model.Minimize(makespan)

    # Solve model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solution_printer = SolutionPrinter()
    status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)

    # Print final solution.
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        for job_id in all_jobs:
            print('Job %i:' % job_id)
    #         for task_id in range(len(jobs[job_id])):
    #             start_value = solver.Value(starts[(job_id, task_id)])
    #             machine = -1
    #             duration = -1
    #             selected = -1
    #             for alt_id in range(len(jobs[job_id][task_id])):
    #                 if solver.Value(presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)]):
    #                     duration = jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][0]
    #                     machine = jobs[job_id][task_id][alt_id][1]
    #                     selected = alt_id
    #             print(
    #                 ' task_%s_%s starts at %s (alt %s, machine %s, duration %s)' %
    #                 (job_id, task_id, start_value, selected, machine, duration))
    
    #     print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    #     print('Optimal objective value: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    #     print('Statistics')
    #     print('  - conflicts : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
    #     print('  - branches  : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
    #     print('  - wall time : %f s' % solver.WallTime())
    else:
        print("INFEASIBLE")
    
jobshop()
```

The output makespan allows for jobs to be run simultaneously on a machine and only outputs the makespan for the longest job.  I am struggling to see where/how to add the appropriate AddNoOverlap/AddCumulative constraints (given their list required format) to prevent a machine from running a task from any job simultaneously and provide the makespan for all the jobs.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Add all intervals in a cumulative constraint ? There are multiple examples that uses them.

Comment: Laurent, thank you for the thought.  I am fairly new to python, so I apologize for perhaps simple question.  When I attempt to do this via l_presence interval it does not change anything, and when I try to add a interval for the jobs it also results in an error/does not change anything.

Comment: have you looked at examples? gate_scheduling_sat.py, rcpsp_sat.py ?

Comment: I have, when I add cumulative constraints, the intervals_per_resource is empty for the machines, and when I add a job interval, it immediately goes infeasible if I constrain capacity to anything less than the number of jobs.

I am guessing I have an iteration problem, but am unable to find it. 

I updated my original code with the new code.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: this is just all wrong. Please look at the flexible_jobshop_sat.py first, then jobshop_sat.cc for the cumulative part.